# Syntax Error on Really Simple IF x CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a tic tac toe game in sql server 2008.
This is what I have so far:

```
print '
==========================================================
Tic Tac Toe - SQL Server 2008 - My Name - 10/30/2014
==========================================================
To insert an ''X'', type EXEC pMakeMove row, column, skip.
Row and column must both be between 1 and 3 or you will 
automatically forfeit your move. skip can be either 1 or 
0, with 1 specifying that you''d like to skip your turn. 

You will always start first, unless you decide to skip 
your first turn. You will always be ''X'' and the PC will 
always be ''O''.

When you make a move, the PC will automatically make a 
move as well, the game will check for a winner after 
each of these moves.

After each move, the game board is displayed.

On a winning move, the game board is displayed, a
message is displayed, and the board is cleared.
'

if not exists (
        select * 
        from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
        where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
        and TABLE_NAME = 'TicTacToe')
begin
    create table TicTacToe
    (
        [row] as int,
        [1] as bit,
        [2] as bit,
        [3] as bit
    )

    insert into TicTacToe (row,[1],[2],[3]) values (1,null,null,null),(2,null,null,null),(3,null,null,null)
end
else
begin
    update TicTacToe set [1]=null,[2]=null,[3]=null
end
```

And this is the random error I'm getting:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

I don't see any obvious reason for this.

It's forcing me to add more details. That's really all the details you need. StackOverflow is stupid sometimes.

Comment: I'm not SQL server expert, but shouldn't you be ending your statements with a semicolon?

Comment: @Yuck They're fine. It's just convenience for writing the game. Using `[]` should make that a non-issue.

Comment: @JNevill I added semi-colons after each statement, I still got the same error.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Are you sure it supports multi-row `VALUES` clause? But yeah, column definitions definitely can't have `col AS datatype`, need to be `col datatype`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand SQL Server 2008. It does. I removed it now, dunno how I forgot that lol... SQL Server didn't give a very accurate error anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your statement to this:

```
create table TicTacToe
(
    row int,
    [1] bit,
    [2] bit,
    [3] bit
)
```

When defining a table you can't write `as`. It's a relatively common mistake and the parser isn't very helpful about it.

Comment: Yeah, strange that it didn't catch that.

Answer (score 1):

enclose `row` reserved keyword in [] and also missing ;

remove as also

```
create table TicTacToe
(
    [row]  int,
    [1]  bit,
    [2]  bit,
    [3]  bit
);
```

Comment: Really the only problem was the use of `as` in the `create` statement.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. Row isn't a reserved word in sql server.

Comment: @Yuck You're right.. add that as the answer and I'll accept. Thank you.

Comment: @yuck, you are right, i forgot to mention in the comment